# Print number pattern with a single for loop without an if statements

Tags: c, pseudocode

I need to print the following pattern using a single for-loop without if statements.

```
1
21
321
```

I first tried to understand the logic and coded it using 2 for loops:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= num; i++) {
      int temp = i;
      for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            printf("%d", temp);
            temp--;
      }
      printf("\n");
}
```

However, I have no clue on how to approach this without a for loop AND no if statements.
Any hints/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First element is 1x10^0. Second element is first + 2x10^1. Third is second + 3x10^2. See a pattern?

Comment: `fputs("1\n21\n321\n", stdout)`.  If you want to be more general, you should provide details.  What is the 11th line of your desired output (in the general case)?  Probably, you want to never go past "987654321", so you can just build that string and do something like `char *t = "987654321"; for( char *s = t + 8; ...; s--) puts(s);`

Comment: The superficial solution is to concatenate previous string behind the "i" in current loop. The clever way is as @Mat commented, to find out the mathematical pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the previous line and use it to produce new one. Here's naive implementation, working for up to 9 lines.

```
int main()
{
    int num = 3;
    char buffer[100] = {0};
    char temp_buffer[200] = {0};

    for (int i = 1 ; i <= num; i++) {
        sprintf(temp_buffer, "%d%s", i, buffer);
        printf("%s\n", temp_buffer);
        strcpy(buffer, temp_buffer);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right, the numbers were reversed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a loop that will print integer `321` three times.
2. Modify loop print statement to print *remainder* of `321` divided by `10`. Each line will now print `1`.
3. After print statement, multiply divider by `10`, so that after each loop iteration divider is 10 times bigger.

Answer (score -1):

- Try to write loops as close to the most trivial/canonical form as possible:

  `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`

  That means: avoid iterating starting from 1, avoid comparing with <=, avoid down-counting loops. There's a place for all of these things but avoid them when you can for the sake of readability and keeping things simple. As a bonus, readable loops are very often also fast loops.
- In this case 2 `for` loops isn't a bad idea. You can consider the output a matrix of sorts, then have an outer `for` loop for "rows" and the inner one for "columns".
- Write the outer `for` loop in the canonical form I showed above where `n` would be your maximum, such as `3`.
- Write the inner `for` loop so that it iterates from zero up to "rows" - the outer loop iterator. However, you don't want to write `0`, `10` and so on so you should also compensate for this by adding + 1. So the upper limit condition of the inner loop could be `cols < (rows+1)`.
- Then when printing in the inner loop (assuming you took my advise to make it up-counting), print descending by starting at your max value `rows+1` then subtract the current value. That is `(rows+1) - cols`.
- Change new line in the outer loop, after printing each row, like you are already doing.

Result:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #define MAX 5
>
>
> int main (void)
> {
>   for(int rows=0; rows<MAX; rows++)
>   {
>     for(int cols=0; cols<(rows+1); cols++)
>       printf("%d",(rows+1)-cols);
>     printf("\n");
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: From the problem statement: “I need to print the following pattern using a single for-loop”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well too bad then, because I'm only concerned about teaching good programming practices and not how to create obfuscated crap caused by artificial requirements made up by some academic not living in the real world where computer programs are designed. I also believe that deliberate code obfuscation is considered off-topic on SO, as per some meta consensus. Such questions could be posted as a puzzle challenge on the Code Golf site, not here.